# Getting the Notification alert body and store it on a String

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a problem on how to get the push notification alert body.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification: (NSDictionary*)userInfo{

 NSLog(@"Received notification: %@", userInfo);

 }
```

However, It returns the correct notification value.

my NSLog

```
2013-08-06 05:58:29.340 CareProject[4477:907] Received notification: {
aps =     {
alert = "Are you available to visit Facility 1?";
badge = 1;
sound = default;
};
```

}

I dont know how to get the alert body which is. "Are you available to visit Facility 1?"
I want to Store it via String and display it on a label on my ViewController.m. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access that easily:

```
[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"]
```

Comment: Like This? NSString *str = userInfo[@"alert"];   it gives me an error.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo. Should be NSString *str = userInfo[@"aps"][@"alert"];

Comment: Still im having an error on that line. "Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type 'NSDictionary *'". Any Idea what might be the cause? I put that code on  didReceiveRemoteNotification method.

Comment: what do u mean by long-hand?

Comment: In my original response, I used dictionary shorthand for the keys (userInfo[@"aps]) but because the compiler doesn't know that userInfo's object at key "aps" is a dictionary, that failed. Long hand (using objectForKey:) will work because it informs the compiler that item is a dictionary first.

Comment: So to further clarify, your example would be: `NSString *str = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"];`

Comment: Please update this question by marking this as the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

From here: [iOS Developer Lib](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

> The userInfo dictionary contains the **aps key** whose value is another dictionary. Although you should not need the information in the aps dictionary, you can retrieve its contents using the following keys:
>
> **alert** — The value is either a string for the alert message or a dictionary with two keys: body and show-view. The value of the body key is a string containing the alert message and the value of the show-view key is a Boolean. If the value of the show-view key is false, the alert’s View button is not shown. The default is to show the View button which, if the user taps it, launches the application.

So, essentially, you need to:

```
NSDictionary *apsDict = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"]; 
if (apsDict != nil) {
    id alertObj = [apsDict objectForKey:@"alert"];
    if ([alertObj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] == YES) {
        NSString *alert = alertObj;
        if ([alert length] > 0) {
            // use alert as NSString
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSString*alertBody=[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"]objectForKey:@"alert"];
```